# Formula in spreadsheet being converted to a custom list

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list, excel, calculated-column-formula, formula

I am currently trying to take an existing spreadsheet and replicate this as a SharePoint list.

The spreadsheet contains the following columns:
**Received** - This will be a number column with 0 decimal places values entered manually
**Total In Queue** - Same as above
**Oldest Date** - Date Column values manually added
**Worked** - This will be a calculated column
**Report Category** - Choice (Let's call them 1,2 and 3)
There are 3 categories for each item 1 for each mailbox being reported on. There will be one item added per day for each category.

**Worked** is what is causing difficulty. The Calculation will need to reference information that doesn't yet exist. The formula in excel is

> =SUM(B1,D1-D2)

In Terms of columns this would translate to

> =SUM([Received],[Total in Queue]-[Next days Total in Queue])

Now as the required information for the calculation won't exist until the next day SharePoint will not allow for this formula to be used. I need to be able to replicate this and everything I have tried has either updated today's item for all 3 categories skewing the data or hasn't had any effect. Can anyone suggest an approach I could Take?

Comment: Hello, its SharePoint Online or Server? How often should run this, must it be immediately or can be it done within 5minutes?

Comment: Hello, This is SP2013OP. I'll give you more context on it's purpose. We have a mailbox for requesting call backs. This is to report on the amount coming in, amount worked etc. The report will be added once a day(single item) and will need to update the previous days report with today's total in queue in order to perform the calculation above. There are 3 categories of report and one item will need to be added for each everyday.

Comment: and it need to update all previous days or only the previous one ?

Comment: can you provide as some picture with data as example and what everything must change? Thank you

Comment: Could you use a scheduled task that runs a powershell script that performs this calculation? It's easy to get the last two items added and do this calculation you asked for in powershell.

Comment: I think I may have come up with a solution but due to the logic used I won't know if this works until tomorrow. Once tested I'll post results and if my solution doesn't work I'll post some screen shots and better description of exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: okey, :) we will wait, good luck!

Comment: Ok... My solution didn't work. I'm going to edit the question to try and explain the exact requirements the best I can.

Comment: can you provide us some screenshots of the values ? the last field is SUM of all of the past days?

Comment: Screenshots please? For better imagine whats going on? You probably need to use workflow for calculating the values.